# Change the hex code in c # exe

Tags: c#, replace, hex-editors

How can I change the image with C # as the hex codes http://prntscr.com/1oiw50

```
byte[] byt = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\\\a.exe");
string hex = new SoapHexBinary(byt).ToString().Replace("504B0304", "424C0304");
File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\\\b.exe", new SoapHexBinary(hex).Value);
```

Exe does not work this way, but I'm trying.

Comment: Iterate on  `byt`, find 4 consecutive bytes `50` `4B` `03` `04` and replace them with the desired value (BTW: don't try to convert arbitrary byte array to string).

Comment: String to Byte type, type CONVERT know how to convert a byte again after changing.

Is it possible to give a solid example of bi working properly.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. If what you ask is how to do replacing on a byte array, No I am too lazy to write a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    byte[] byt = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\a.exe");
    for (int i = 0; i <= byt.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (byt[i] == 80)
        {
            if (byt[i + 1] == 75)
            {
                if (byt[i + 2] == 3)
                {
                    if (byt[i + 3] == 4)
                    {
                        byt[i] = 66;
                        byt[i + 1] = 76;
                        byt[i + 2] = 3;
                        byt[i + 3] = 4;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\b.exe", byt);
```

Do you have a bug in this code.I turned to decimal hex codes byt changed accordingly.

Comment: `i + 3` can be bigger than `byt.Length - 1`. Check for overflows. I guess it should be `i < byt.Length - 4`

Comment: I need not have picked him +3 percent. Exe error, but also allows for some reason. I wonder where I make mistakes. If you want to give an example Exe.